# How to store data in cookies of browser

Tags: php, codeigniter, session-cookies

In codeigniter, how do I store data in the cookies of the browser?

I am doing this

```
$this->session->set_userdata('above_eighteen',"1");
```

Is this the right way to do so, and on clearing cookies will this be unset?

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the documentation http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html,

**set cookie:**

```
$cookie = array(
    'name'   => 'The Cookie Name',
    'value'  => 'The Value',
    'expire' => '86500',
    'domain' => '.some-domain.com',
    'path'   => '/',
    'prefix' => 'myprefix_',
    'secure' => TRUE
);

$this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
```

**get cookie:**

```
cookie('The Cookie Name');
```

**delete cookie:**

```
delete_cookie("The Cookie Name");
```